# npm error when deploying to heroku with sendgrid module

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, sendgrid

I just installed the Sendgrid npm module along with the corresponding Heroku add-on (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid), but now I can't deploy. Not sure what the dependency error is, but here's my logs:

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.0
       Using npm version: 1.2.12
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.1.0.tgz
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.1.0.tgz
   npm ERR! Error: spawn ENOENT
   npm ERR!     at errnoException (child_process.js:945:11)
   npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:736:34)
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
   npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
   npm ERR! or email it to:
   npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-350-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-2mQ6/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-yvGj/cli.js" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1y5wgumdk981a
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.12
   npm ERR! syscall spawn
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_1y5wgumdk981a/npm-debug.log
   npm ERR! not ok code 0
 !     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

My package.json has the following dependencies:

```
 {
    "name": "Test"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "3.1.*"
  , "stylus": ">= 0.0.1"
  , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
  , "sendgrid": ">= 0.2.5"
  , "ejs": ">= 0.8.3"
  , "path": ">= 0.4.9"
},
  "engines": {
     "node": ">=0.8.19",
      "npm": ">=1.2.10"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? My app deploys fine if I remove the Sendgrid module.

Comment: Figured it out. Realized I was using node version 0.10.0, which might not have been supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a lower version of node? It looks like 0.10.0 is just released and may still have some issues that need to be resolved.